# How to access data field in Dialogflow?

Tags: ios, chatbot, dialogflow-es

As the Dialogflow documentations states, the `data` field represents

> Additional data required for performing the action on the client side.
>   The data is sent to the client in the original form and is not
>   processed by Dialogflow.

How should one access it in the iOS framework?

```
request?.setMappedCompletionBlockSuccess({ (request, response) in
...
}
```

I couldn't find it in the response object and can't find any documentation for iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: Can u narrow down the question or paste code snippet.?

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to do. https://medium.com/@pallavtrivedi03/how-to-make-a-webhook-for-dialogflow-fulfillment-d02835cc50bf

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit vague (can you edit and narrow it down?), but i think you got it the other way round, what that snippet of documentation that you pasted means is that you are supposed to send that payload to DialogFlow and it will forward it to a connected Client (e.g Messenger, Slack etc) un-touched. It simply means that DialogFlow assumes that you know what you are doing.

Here is a sample Fulfilment response to DialogFlow in JS

```
module.exports.sendGenericMessageWithText = function(message) {
return {
    data: {
        facebook: [
            { 
                text: message 
        ]
    }
}
```

}